# Tengo un problema al importar random

Tags: python, vscode, pylance

es mi primera vez acá y tengo un problema. Cuando escribo "import random" me sale un mensaje que dice: no se puede acceder a "random". Intenté de todo, hasta restablecí el pc. (Instalé VS Code desde la microsoft store y mi versión de python es la 3.11.6)

edit: (mi version de VS Code es la 1.83.0, y la version de pylance es la v2023.10.10)

Adjunto imagen del problema:

[image: imagen1]

Comment: Yo, a pesar de ese mensaje de advertencia que he obtenido en otros modulos, puedo ejecutar mis scripts normalmente. No se que signifique, pero me suena a un falso positivo.

Comment: Bienvenido, @mr-wayne. ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta las versiones concretas de visual code y pylance que usas?

Comment: listo, ya añadí las versiones de vs code y pylance

Comment: Vale, pensaba que era uno de los problemas de pylance, pero veo que usas una versión moderno. Yo uso vscode en inglés y no veía estos mensajes en español. Eso que ves es una _mala traducción_ de _"random" is not accessed_, o sea, que te advierte que estás importando un módulo que luego no usas. No es ningún error. Usando **ruff** (otro linter moderno) te dice _imported, but unused_ que es algo más claro.